# how to convert json string nested to json object in dart flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

the json string comes like this ,

[[{"id":39,"mail":"mail@mm04.com","password":"q149","name":"Anthony","photo":"a14.png","dateac":"1900-01-01T18:36:36.000Z"},{"id":40,"mail":"mail@mm04.com","password":"q14","name":"Anthony","photo":"a3.png","dateac":"1900-01-01T18:36:36.000Z"}],{"fieldCount":0,"affectedRows":0,"insertId":0,"serverStatus":34,"warningCount":0,"message":"","protocol41":true,"changedRows":0}]

I need to convert to two objects: on the one hand a list of people and the other a control record, I appreciate any guide I am new to dart and I have been trying for several days. Thanks.

Comment: You must improve your data format and question, however there are tools that convert JSON structure into Dart structure like this [tool](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/), it may be of help to you.

Comment: thanks Ουιλιαμ Αρκευα, I tried the link you indicate but it only generates the class of the first part of the json string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your JSON data, it has two parts: one is variable (List) and the another is fixed (Map). So you need to think how to deal with that structure, one example:

```
List<Object> : L
    L[0] : List<Object> : K
        K[i] : Map<String, Object> : where i = 0.. K.length-1
            - convert every element to an instance of Person class
    L[1] : Map<String, Object>
        - convert this element to an instance of Control class
```

Respect to classes to use:

```
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class Person {
    Person({
        @required this.id,
        @required this.mail,
        @required this.password,
        @required this.name,
        @required this.photo,
        @required this.dateac,
    });

    int id;
    String mail;
    String password;
    String name;
    String photo;
    DateTime dateac;

    factory Person.fromRawJson(String str) => Person.fromJson(json.decode(str));

    String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

    factory Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Person(
        id: json["id"],
        mail: json["mail"],
        password: json["password"],
        name: json["name"],
        photo: json["photo"],
        dateac: DateTime.parse(json["dateac"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "mail": mail,
        "password": password,
        "name": name,
        "photo": photo,
        "dateac": dateac.toIso8601String(),
    };
}

class Control {
    Control({
        @required this.fieldCount,
        @required this.affectedRows,
        @required this.insertId,
        @required this.serverStatus,
        @required this.warningCount,
        @required this.message,
        @required this.protocol41,
        @required this.changedRows,
    });

    int fieldCount;
    int affectedRows;
    int insertId;
    int serverStatus;
    int warningCount;
    String message;
    bool protocol41;
    int changedRows;

    factory Control.fromRawJson(String str) => Control.fromJson(json.decode(str));

    String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

    factory Control.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Control(
        fieldCount: json["fieldCount"],
        affectedRows: json["affectedRows"],
        insertId: json["insertId"],
        serverStatus: json["serverStatus"],
        warningCount: json["warningCount"],
        message: json["message"],
        protocol41: json["protocol41"],
        changedRows: json["changedRows"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "fieldCount": fieldCount,
        "affectedRows": affectedRows,
        "insertId": insertId,
        "serverStatus": serverStatus,
        "warningCount": warningCount,
        "message": message,
        "protocol41": protocol41,
        "changedRows": changedRows,
    };
}
```

Generated by https://app.quicktype.io/

Comment: Thanks Ουιλιαμ Αρκευα, with your answer I have resolved the extraction of the data.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> This is the Object Model Of Your JSON data Now Call the http method and get the data via using this model .
> ```

```
class serverModel {
      int id;
      String mail;
      String password;
      String name;
      String photo;
      String dateac;
    
      serverModel(
          {this.id, this.mail, this.password, this.name, this.photo, this.dateac});
    
      serverModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        id = json['id'];
        mail = json['mail'];
        password = json['password'];
        name = json['name'];
        photo = json['photo'];
        dateac = json['dateac'];
      }
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        data['id'] = this.id;
        data['mail'] = this.mail;
        data['password'] = this.password;
        data['name'] = this.name;
        data['photo'] = this.photo;
        data['dateac'] = this.dateac;
        return data;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class FeeConcessionModel {
  int id;
  String mail;
  String password;
  String name;
  String photo;
  String dateac;

  FeeConcessionModel(
      {this.id, this.mail, this.password, this.name, this.photo, this.dateac});

  FeeConcessionModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    mail = json['mail'];
    password = json['password'];
    name = json['name'];
    photo = json['photo'];
    dateac = json['dateac'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['mail'] = this.mail;
    data['password'] = this.password;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['photo'] = this.photo;
    data['dateac'] = this.dateac;
    return data;
  }
}
```

**You can use given below website to convert the jaon to Dart object**
https://app.quicktype.io/